# Near-infrared EM spectrum and uses in biology (specifically in botany/vegetation)

Tags: botany, light, color, vegetation

A little explanation for my problem:

I have a large dataset - images of aerial scans of my country. These images are available in both RGB and RGBN colors - N specifying the near-infrared color channel. I plan to  use this data/images to make a computer-simulated realistic landscape game. However, the data has a resolution of around 15cm, which means I can't really expect realistic depictions of individual blades of grass. I will need some kind of interpolation.

I could manage pretty well with the RGB colors, but I would like to know some uses of the near-infrared color channel for this kind of problem - which is analysing vegetation, ground, etc. - and how could it help me with this kind of project.

I did try doing some research: I found this neat little picture that illustrates how we can analyze if a plant is healthy or not.

[image]

> Green vegetation (left) absorbs visible light and reflects near-infrared light; Sparse vegetation (right) reflects more visible light and less near-infrared light. ([source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Green-vegetation-left-absorbs-visible-light-and-reflects-near-infrared-light-Sparse_fig1_266947355))

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what your question is here - are you looking for data on how to resolve types of plants based on NIR or something else? The [GIS Stack](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) might be more help. There's also some info in the original publication for your image [here](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0108548), which you incidentally should attribute correctly!

Comment: To be fair, it's a very general question. I am looking for a botanist's view on this - I am not very well versed in botany nor biology. I'm just looking for some resources as to how to approach this issue. The GIS StackExchange users are not biologists - I believe I'd be redirected to the Biology StackExchange and so on again.

Comment: There's quite a bit of information on this topic around - try this search at [Pubmed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=near-infrared+vegetation+cover)